# Identify records in data extension from CSV file

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql, csv

I am trying to identify a series of records in a data extension. 
I have a CSV file containing all the records that I want to identify in ly data extension but I don't know to proceed to clearly identify those records in Marketing Cloud.

My purpose is to send an email via Journey Builder to those identified records.

Many thanks for your help,

Grégoire

Comment: If you have a file with the records you want to send to, why not create a new Data Extension, upload your CSV file and use it as an entry source for your journey?

Comment: Are you missing some crucial information like the subscriberkey or subscriberid or why do you need to find them in your dataextension?

Comment: I do miss crucial information. I only have a contact number in the CSV file

Comment: Can you add the data structure of your Data Extension and the CSV file to the original question?

Comment: @GrégoireSarrola If my answer helped solve your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark symbol on the left hand side of it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @zuzannamj, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I am not allowed to share any information from that CSV file. Grégoire

Comment: I didn't ask for the data, but for the data structure :-) I'm glad that it's solved now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are missing some information necessary for the send in the best case you would create two new data extensions:

1. CSV-Import Data Extension (with all the fields you need from your CSV)
2. Data Extension for your Send/Journey (with all the fields of DE 1 and all the necessary additional information you already have in Marketing Cloud)

In order for this to work you need to have one column/value that your Marketing Cloud Data has in common with your CSV data and is suitable to act as a unique identifier for a match.

You perform the following steps after data extension creation:

1. Import the CSV to DE 1
2. Create and execute a SQL query activity in Automation Studio which joins the DE 1 with your Subscriber Data from another Data Extension in Marketing Cloud and writes to DE 2

Your query could look somewhat like this (however this is just pseudo-code as I don't know your data structure):

```sql
SELECT
  CSVUniqueId,
  CSVField1,
  MCDataField1,
  MCDataField2
FROM
  DE1
INNER JOIN
  SFMCData
ON
  CSVUniqueId = MCUniqueId
```

Where CSVUniqueId and MCUniqueId would be the field holding the same information in your CSV and Marketing Cloud which lets you tie the data together. As you mentioned in a comment your "contact number" could be such a field for example.

Comment: Hi Markus, thanks a lot for your comment! I solved my problem using your process.